# Plymouth script update and 'initramfs –u' quadrupled fsck time

Tags: plymouth, initramfs, fsck

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 Netbook Remix.
I updated my *Plymouth script* for my splash screens and ran `initramfs -u` to use the new *Plymouth script*.

After doing this my `fsck` time at bootup went from about 5 minutes to over 20 minutes.
I checked my disk usage for `/dev/sda1` and it went from 3527472 K to 4769008 K (a 35% increase).

This is for customer installations around the world and this increase in boot times would not be acceptable.  I figure I must be doing something wrong, but do not know what I should be doing instead. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I tried an experiment and turned the splash screens off by removing quiet splash and the boot time when down to 1 minute 36 seconds. There definitely seems to be an interaction between plymouth and fsck. Could they be competing for memory space or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: You're installing 10.04, which is EOL, to customers around the world? And from an Atom? There may be something you're not saying, but you may want to upgrade to a supported desktop release such as 12.04 or 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The problem was as I suspected in the update to the question. I am running on an Atom processor @ 1.66 GHZ with 1 GB of memory and with the new splash screen the fsck and new plymouth splash screen were competing for resources more than my previous splash screen. I updated the plymouth code and simplified it and removed all unnecessary features and code and my fsck times returned to about 5 minutes.